# How to pip install django-selectable

Tags: jquery, python, django, jquery-ui, selectable

I am new to django and programming in general.

I am trying to use the django selectable but I don't know what to do when they say in the docs:

To install:

```
pip install django-selectable
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the commandline, type

```
pip install django-selectable
```

If for some reason, you do not have `pip` installed: Check this [link](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/).

This would put the `django-selectable` app in your python's `dist-packages`, and it would be available to you as a 3rd party app in the django application you are building.

[PIP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) is A tool for installing and managing Python packages.

Answer (score 1):

Check this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

Basically, you need to install pip on your operating system, so you can use it from terminal (cmd on Windows).

Pip installs python packages so you can then import them from your code.

The command you are showing, says to install the `django-selectable` package, so you have to paste that on terminal.

Normally, for every pip installation you'll need to do this:

```
pip install <module>
```

Where `<module>` could be any module that is available with pip.